# Why does my div stop on the left when resizing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, resize, position

I earlier learned something interesting and tried to play a bit with it, however I noticed something I never noticed before.

When I resize my window over my div width, it doesn't evenly hide my div but stop on the left and start hiding from the right.

After some research I found out differens answers like giving a positionning would lead to such thing but considering how basic my code is it seems to not be the reason...

Here is my code :http://jsfiddle.net/L9Srn/5/

```
<div id="container"></div>
#container {
    background: red;
    margin: auto;
}
var box= $('#container'),
    ratio= 0.363,
    height= 400;

box.height(height).width(height*ratio);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the way browsers/CSS work.  When elements are too wide to fit in the window, they stop at the left and overflow to the right.

Off the top of my head, the only ways to have things hide to the left of the browser window on resize are:

1. absolute positioning
2. fixed positioning
3. negative margin
4. negative padding
5. having the part that's disappearing be a background image centered vertically.

Even if you use these methods though you won't be able to scroll to the left to see the content that is cut off.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explaination ! do you think you could show me an example for any of these example to see how it works ? for the abolute positioning for example ?

Comment: You could set it to `position: absolute; left: 50%;` and then give it a negative `margin-left` of half the box width. You just have to create a variable that grabs the box width and halves it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand a lot more the methods I could use.